# Holding different instances of the same class in GAE Datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo, datastore

Extremly confusing title, i know.

Hello, i am facing some funky issues here.

I have a property-class, like this

```
@PersistenceCapable 
public class Property implements Serializable
{
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    @Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "gae.encoded-pk", value = "true")
    private String key;
        //...
}
```

Now, i also have two other classes. Lets call them Factory and Store.
They both have propertys, like this:

```
@PersistenceCapable 
public class Factory implements Serializable
{
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    @Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "gae.encoded-pk", value = "true")
    private String key;
    @Persistent
    private String m_Name;
    @Persistent
    private List<Property> m_FactoryProperties;
}
```

and

```
@PersistenceCapable 
public class Store implements Serializable
{
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    @Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "gae.encoded-pk", value = "true")
    private String key;
    @Persistent
    private String m_Name;
    @Persistent
    private List<Property> m_StoreProperties;
}
```

While this does look simple, it will not work.
And i have no idea why, im guessing its index-related, as in the Data Viewer of GAE there is either a m_FactoryProperties_INTEGER_IDX or a m_StoreProperties_INTEGER_IDX when i view property entities. (They never appear at the same time).

(Does not work if i rename to lists to m_Propertys either)...

Is this not possible?
I COULD make a FactoryProperty- and StoreProperty-class, but that would feel horrible wrong.
Another solution im thinking about is making a superclass that holds a list of Propertys, and then have Factory and Store inherit from this class, that SHOULD make them share the index, i think...
Should i just skip the owned relationships and go for unowned?

I feel that i  may just missing something crucial.
Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an owned relationship property can only belong to one class.
you also should add a link to the property in the parent class then

ex.

Proprety

```
@Persistent
private Store store;
```

Store

```
@Persistent(mappedBy = "store")
private List<Property> protperties;
```

If you want to use the same properties in the store and factory class you have to go with the unowned relationship solution.

Factory

```
@Persistent
private Set<Key> properties;
```

Store

```
@Persistent
private Set<Key> properties;
```